# How create a smart playlist that shows only full albums in my library?

Tags: itunes, music, playlist, apple-music

Does anyone know how to create a iTunes Playlist that shows only songs in My Library which are part of a complete album in My Library.

Essentially I want to see all my complete albums. You can in Spotify but with Apple Music every song you add to a playlist it assumes you want it added to My Library.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Today iTunes provided an option "Add songs to my music" but it doesn't work for previously added songs

Comment: Yeah I know. It's so frustrating. I have had to delete all music from my library. Luckily this does not remove the songs from Apple's playlists from the playlists but it removes them from the library.

Comment: I have then had to manually add all the albums back to my library.

Comment: Of course you would need to redo any of your own playlists as well

Comment: When i delete a song from My Music it also deletes it from playlists?

Comment: Your playlist or an Apple one?

Comment: My playlist contains apple music songs

Comment: Yup it will do that. If you remove songs from your library which are in an apple playlist it won't.

Comment: No you didn't get my point. Listen, i create a playlist then i add some songs from Apple music. These songs are added also to "My Music" as single songs. When i want to see only complete albums, it is impossible. I need to delete these single songs from My Music somehow but when i delete a song it also deletes from my playlist which makes me crazy.

Comment: Did you add them using iPhone with latest iOS?

Comment: Nope i am talking about Mac Os X

Comment: An alternate way to do this—that I still don’t know how to implement—is to limit the results to only albums with X tracks, so that if you have fewer than, say, 5 tracks in an album, it won’t display it. There’s an iOS app that does this, but I know of no way to do it on the Mac.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apple has released a fix for this. In Settings>Music it lets you toggle between showing playlist songs in library or not.

Comment: Where is Settings>Music ??

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to automate this functionality in iTunes today.  To do so, the system would need to know how many songs were in each album and that isn't immediately available.  Plus, what if you have an album with twelve songs and you only have eleven, but you still want it in the list.  Or what about singles that have only one or two songs.  Are these "complete" albums?

In any case, the only way I know to do this is to mark complete albums manually.

For example, you could put a note in "Comments" like "CompleteAlbum" and build a playlist for all files with Comments that contain "CompleteAlbum".  If you want to stay out of the comments, you could use the Disc X of Y, clearing the Disc # for non-album tracks and setting it to 1 (or 2 or whatever) for albums.  Then, you build a playlist that looks for songs with Disc # >= 1.  It's up to you.

You just have to remember to do that for each album you add, but your playlist would contain all your 'complete albums'.

Comment: It actually does have this information, in “Track #”; i.e. “3 of 11.” So it knows there’s 11 songs in that album.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer for this, but I eliminated about 200 songs from my latest Smart Playlist (e.g., 2017 songs) by adding criteria of Album does not contain text "Single". There's unfortunately no filter for "of" field for total count of tracks, because then you could filter out anything where this is set to 1 (1 of 1 tracks, vs. 1 of 13 on an album, for example).